# Juntar dos values en un campo SQL y evitar warning

Tags: php, html, mysql, base-de-datos, checkbox

Tengo un formulario con un `input checkbox` que incluye dos variables, ambas seleccionables al mismo tiempo. Al momento de que el usuario elige ambas, se imprime un solo `value` en el campo asignado en mi base de datos. Adjunto el respectivo código:

**Formulario**

```
<div class="methodcheck">
    <div class="methodtitle">
        <p>Elegir Método</p><i class="helpmetbutton fa fa-question-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkP2P" name="method" value="P2P">
    <label for="checkP2P">P2P Binance</label>

    <input type="checkbox" id="checkF2F" name="method" value="F2F">
    <label for="checkF2F">F2F</label>
</div>
```

Código `PHP` utilizado para imprimir datos seleccionados por el usuario en la base de datos:

```
<?php 
    include 'php/conexion_be.php';
    if(isset($_POST['publicar'])){
        $id = $_SESSION['id'];
        $provincia = $_POST['provincia'];
        $localidad = $_POST['localidad'];
        $currency = $_POST['currency'];
        $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
        $fee = $_POST['fee'];
        $operation = $_POST['operation'];
        $method = $_POST['method'];

        $query = "INSERT INTO anuncios(usuario, fecha, provincia, localidad, moneda, cantidad, comision, operacion, metodo)
        VALUES('$id', now(), '$provincia', '$localidad', '$currency', '$quantity', '$fee', '$operation', '$method')";

        $ejecutar = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);
        if($ejecutar){
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
            echo 'setTimeout(function () {';
            echo 'swal("¡Anuncio publicado!","Ya podes verlo en la sección de anuncios generales","success").then( function(val) {';
            echo 'if (val == true) window.location.href = \'market.php\';';
            echo '});';
            echo '}, 200);  </script>';
            exit();
        }else{
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
            echo 'setTimeout(function () {';
            echo 'swal("Algo salió mal...","No se pudo publicar tu anuncio. Por favor intenta de nuevo.","error").then( function(val) {';
            echo 'if (val == true) window.location.href = \'../registro.php\';';
            echo '});';
            echo '}, 200);  </script>';
        }
        mysqli_close($conexion);
    }
?>
```

Básicamente lo que busco es que si el usuario selecciona los dos `checkbox`, se impriman los dos `values` en la base de datos y no uno solo como actualmente sucede.

También otro inconveniente es que si el usuario no selecciona ninguno de los dos, se imprime un

> warning: undefined array key

sobre la variable no escogida.

Me gustaría saber también como poder evitar esto sin necesidad de agregar un `required` a los `checkbox`.

Desde ya muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unir valores en un solo campo no es una buena práctica, aunque se puede lograr.

Lo primero es cambiar el atributo `name` para diferenciarlos...

```
<div class="methodcheck">
    <div class="methodtitle">
        <p>Elegir Método</p>
        <i class="helpmetbutton fa fa-question-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkP2P" name="p2p" value="P2P">
    <label for="checkP2P">P2P Binance</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkF2F" name="f2f" value="F2F">
    <label for="checkF2F">F2F</label>
</div>
```

Luego validar si vienen vacíos o no y concatenarlos en `php`...

```
$p2p = empty($_POST['p2p']) ? NULL : $_POST['p2p'];
$f2f = empty($_POST['f2f']) ? NULL : $_POST['f2f'];
$method = $p2p.','.$f2f;
```

Para solucionar el `warning`, simplemente creas el campo en la tabla y lo configuras para que acepte valores NULL, *`mySql` los crea así por defecto*. Si ya lo tienes creado y configurado como NOT NULL, lo puedes modificar a través de `phpMyAdmin` o con el siguiente query:

```
ALTER TABLE anuncios MODIFY metodo VARCHAR(3) NULL;
```

Personalmente, agregaría dos columnas en la base de datos para registrar por separado el método que llegue del formulario.

Así envías uno, los dos métodos o incluso ninguno si es el caso *dado que no quieres usar el atributo `required`*.

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Funcionó todo a la perfección y al primer intento :D